# Entity Framework: reload data if changes are occurred

Tags: c#, entity-framework, validation

I need to load data from SQL Express and keep them valid.

This code loads data after 1sec sleep. No matter is there changes or not.

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    while (true)
    {
        ReloadData();   

        Thread.Sleep(1000);
    }
}

static void ReloadData()
{
    using (var db = new ProverkaEntities())
    {
        var ls = db.texts.ToList();
        foreach (var s in ls)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(s.text);
        }
        Console.WriteLine("======");
    }
}
```

Is there some way to reload data only if changes are occurred?

Comment: You mean, changes done by a different system?
Why you need them reloaded? Can't you make the particular query to know if that thing you need has changed?

Comment: To be notified whenever a change occures in database, you need to use SQL Notification or Service Broker.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The truth is out there: [How to use SqlDependency to get the notification in Entity Framework](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/How-to-use-SqlDependency-5c0da0b3)

Don't forget to enable Service Broker in your Db properties!